# ProcessPoolExecutor not working even with main check, yet ThreadPoolExecutor works

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to concurrently do Floyd-Warshall, and the code which implements the algorithm concurrently works, but is significantly slower than the Serial version. I've read about GIL and the way it works hence the overhead and slow execution, so I tried to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but it doesn't seem to work even with a `main` check:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

  v = 10
  workers = 8
  graph = generate_grid(v)

  fwc = ConcurrentFloydWarshallUpdated(deepcopy(graph), v, workers)

  fwc_start = time.time()
  with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        results = executor.map(fwc.work, range(workers))
    # shortest_paths = floydWarshall_p1(deepcopy(graph))
  fwc_time = time.time() - fwc_start

  print(f"fwc {fwc_time}")
```

Using `ThreadPoolExecutor` works but `ProcessPoolExecutor` does not reach the end of execution.

Edit: Note that the class `ConcurrentFloydWarshallUpdated` makes use of threading properties such as `Lock()`, `Semaphore()`, and `Condition()`. Do these not work with `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using [`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) instead of [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock), [`multiprocessing.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore) instead of [`threading.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Semaphore)? [`Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition) is same for both.